# Can nth-child be used on one div?

Tags: html, css

It seems from all the examples I seen online to use nth-child I would have to have
more than one div.

It is possible that i can make it work for only one div?

```
.section:nth-child(odd) {

 background-color: red;
}
<div class="section">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:nth-child(odd)` works with any amount of elements. If there's only one, it applies to that first one.

See your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fz3vP/

Answer (score 3):

:nth-child(n) applies to **any number** of elements.

The reason you are not seeing examples online to use nth-child on one div is because, there is no need to use nth-child(n) on single div.